# how to Validate Expire date is bigger than start date in Django Model Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django model form, I want to Validate Expire date is bigger than start date.  this is my code but it is not working. i used clean() method in form.py  but after than form is not submitting.

> form.py

```
class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    app_attributes = {'oninvalid': 'this.setCustomValidity("Application field is required")', 'oninput': 'this.setCustomValidity("")'}
    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    application = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=app_attributes))
    File= forms.FileField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = certificateDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','File' )

        error_messages = {
            'application': {
                'required': ("Application field is required"),
            },
            }
    def clean(self):
        startdate = cleaned_data.get("startdate")
        expiredate = cleaned_data.get("expiredate")
        if expiredate < startdate:
            msg = u"expiredate should be greater than startdate."
            self._errors["expiredate"] = self.error_class([msg])
```

> model.py

```
class certificateDb(models.Model):
Dev = 1
QA = 2
UAT = 3
Production = 4
environment_TYPES = (   (Dev, 'Dev'),   (QA, 'QA'), (UAT, 'UAT'),   (Production, 'Production'), )
application = models.CharField(db_column='Application', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
startdate = models.DateField(null=True)
expiredate = models.DateField(null=True)
environment_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=environment_TYPES)
File = models.FileField(upload_to='CSR/', null=True , blank = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.application
```

Comment: You forgot to get `cleaned_data` in your `clean` method first. Add `cleaned_data = super().clean()` before anything else.

Comment: yes, now working but error message is not shown in the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [official django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) on how to clean multiple fields.

Fix your `clean` method like this:

```py
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        startdate = cleaned_data.get("startdate")
        expiredate = cleaned_data.get("expiredate")

        if startdate and expiredate and expiredate < startdate:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Expiredate should be greater than startdate."
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean() 
    startdate = cleaned_data.get("startdate")
    expiredate = cleaned_data.get("expiredate")
    if startdate and enddate and ( expiredate < startdate ):
        msg = u"expiredate should be greater than startdate."
        raise forms.ValidationError(msg,  code="invalid")
```

the code above `startdate and enddate and ( expiredate < startdate )` is to prevent `TypeError`., when any of the value is None.